# 2D Dynamic Array Allocation and Passing by Reference in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can someone wiser than I please explain to me why the following code segment faults?  There is no problem allocating the memory by reference, but as soon as I try to assign anything or free by reference, segfault occurs.

I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental concept about pointers and passing by reference, hopefully some light can be shed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void allocateMatrix(float ***);
void fillMatrix(float ***);
void freeMatrix(float **);

int main() {
    float **matrix;

    allocateMatrix(&matrix);        // this function calls and returns OK
    fillMatrix(&matrix);            // this function will segfault
    freeMatrix(matrix);             // this function will segfault

    exit(0);
}

void allocateMatrix(float ***m) {
    int i;
    m = malloc(2*sizeof(float*));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        m[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
    }
    return;
}

void fillMatrix(float ***m) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            (*m)[i][j] = 1.0;        // SEGFAULT
        }
    }
    return;
}

void freeMatrix(float **m) {
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        free(m[i]);                  // SEGFAULT
    }
    free(m);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that compiles.  "void allocateMatrix(&m)" is likely not typing m as a float** as expected.  Also, there are not references in C in the same way that there are in C++.

Comment: why are signatures for `freeMatrix` etc different at declaration and definiton ?

Comment: keety, Corbin: sorry copy paste fail, fixed it

Comment: Just to insist on one point, what you are doing here (and have been corrected by Jonathan's answer) are *not* 2D arrays but an emulation of 2D arrays. C has multidimensional arrays directly built into the language that are much easier to use and in particular to allocate. Seeing what seems to be your state of experience with C it would be much more advisable to first learn and use that feature, before going into complicated iterated allocations like this.

Comment: I understand why you would suggest such a thing Jens, and you are correct: it's always easier to walk before you run.  I assume what you mean by the built-in multidimensional arrays is the static, compile-time `float matrix[2][2];`.  This is all well and good, but I need to understand dynamic, pass-by-reference now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One set of problems is here:

```
void allocateMatrix(float ***m) {
    int i;
    m = malloc(2*sizeof(float*));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        m[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
    }
    return;
}
```

You need to assign to `*m` to get the information back to the calling code, and also you will need to allocate to `(*m)[i]` in the loop.

```
void allocateMatrix(float ***m)
{
    *m = malloc(2*sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        (*m)[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
}
```

There's at least a chance that the other functions are OK.  The `fillMatrix()` is written and invoked correctly, though it could be simplified by losing the third `*` from the pointer:

```
void fillMatrix(float **m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            m[i][j] = 1.0;        
    }
}
```

It might be advisable to pass the triple-pointer to `freeMatrix()` so that you can zero the pointer in the calling function:

```
void freeMatrix(float ***m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        free((*m)[i]);
    free(*m);
    *m = 0;
}
```

Calling then becomes:

```
allocateMatrix(&matrix);
fillMatrix(matrix);
freeMatrix(&matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

Good use of indirection. Just try to be consistent with format. It improves readability and reduces errors. e.g.

function calls:

```
    allocateMatrix  &matrix
    fillMatrix  &matrix
    freeMatrix  &matrix
```

declarations

```
void allocateMatrix  float ***m
void fillMatrix  float ***m
void freeMatrix  float ***m
```

handling

```
    (*m)[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(float))
    (*m)[i][j] = 1.0
    free  (*m)[i]
```

Comment: This makes sense, I'll try to implement now.

Answer (score 0):

Returning of pointer from your function is probably the better way to allocate memory:

```
float **allocateMatrix() {
    int i;
    float **m;

    m = malloc(2*sizeof(float *));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        m[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
    }

    return m;
}

int main() {
    float **m;

    m = allocateMatrix();

    /* do other things 
       fillMatrix(matrix);
       freeMatrix(&matrix);
    */
}
```